# A story where Dursleys are not safe anymore and have to be taken to the Order's headquarters, and they see how happy Harry is and are jealous

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

They come and stay the rest of the year at the Order's headquarters and see that there are people there who care, which makes them jealous to the core.

Petunia meets Snape and Snape hates them because they tormented Harry.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What exactly are you looking for, though? A fanfiction, or a story which is canon to the _Harry Potter_ franchise? Also, are you looking for a specific story that you know already exists, or are you asking _if_ such a story exists?

Comment: If looking for an existing story, when and where did you read it?

Comment: @LogicDictates - It seems very specific for anything other than a story-ID

Comment: @Valorum - When in doubt, I prefer to get confirmation from the OP as to their intent, rather than taking anything for granted.